# 2 line pipe delimeted file into assoc array

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I'm looking for a way to cleanly place a 2 line, pipe (|) delimeted file into an assoc array, where the first line is the headers. I've seen some pretty manual examples, but nothing that'll allow for the file to potentially change structure over time.

I'd in effect like to take this:

```
id|first_name|last_name|occupation|age|someotherfield
1|john|doe|cleaner|32|meta
```

and turn it into this:

```
array
    "id" => 1
    "first_name" => john
    "last_name" => doe
    "occupation" => cleaner
    "age" => 32
    "someotherfield" => meta
```

if anyone has any suggestions, I'd really love to hear the best approach.

Comment: You can use fgetcsv and specify the pipe rather than comma for the delimiter. What do you mean by change structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After opening your file, you can fetch the first row to get the column names, then fetch the second row to get the values, then combine them with `array_combine`.

```
$handle = fopen('path/to/yourfile', 'r');
$keys = fgetcsv($handle, 0, '|');
$values = fgetcsv($handle, 0, '|');
$result = array_combine($keys, $values);
```