# Read txt file with php like database

Tags: php, arrays

i export my sql database into text(database.txt) file like this:

```
id|name_sname|identity|address|region|hours|destination|price;
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1|Ezra Mod|123456789|husi, stanilesti, vaslui|HUSI - IASI|20:00|HUSI|100;
2|Ezra Mod|123456789|husi, stanilesti, vaslui|HUSI - IASI|20:00|HUSI|100;
3|Ezra Mod|123456789|husi, stanilesti, vaslui|HUSI - IASI|20:00|HUSI|100;
4|Ezra Mod|123456789|husi, stanilesti, vaslui|HUSI - IASI|20:00|HUSI|100;
5|Ezra Mod|123456789|husi, stanilesti, vaslui|HUSI - IASI|20:00|HUSI|100;
6|Ezra Mod|123456789|husi, stanilesti, vaslui|HUSI - IASI|20:00|HUSI|100;
```

and now i want to read this file with php and put result from each row in another files: contracts.php?id=1 , where id need to be from my **database.txt** ,
I try to read database.txt in this mode:

```
$data = file_get_contents("database.txt"); //read the file
$convert = explode("|", $data); //create array separate by new line

foreach($convert_row as $rand) {
    echo $rand;
    echo "<br /><hr /></br />";
}
```

what need to do for create variables for each value afther/before "|" and each row? something like this:
$id, $name,....

Comment: Relevant: [2 line pipe delimeted file into assoc array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43924974/2943403)

Answer (score 2):

I think keeping the database would be a better approach, both for performance and functionality.

Your issue starts at your second line, the comment there is incorrect:

```
$convert = explode("|", $data); //create array separate by new line
```

That is not splitting by new lines. It is splitting by `|`s, which breaks your columns apart however it will be impossible to find where a column ended/started with this approach. You need to split on new lines or use `file()` to read the file. You then can iterate over the data and build your variables or an array.

```
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $data);
foreach($lines as $key => $line){
    $convert = explode("|", $line); //create array separate by new line
    if($key == 0) {
        foreach($convert as $column_name) {
            $columns[] = $column_name;
        }
    }
    if(is_numeric($convert[0])) {
        $data[$columns[0]][] = $convert[0];
    }
}
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/NIPRE

The `is_numeric` is to ignore the

> ---

in the file `0` will be the `id` so it should always the an integer.

Answer (score 1):

**here is your solution for your database style:**
Live Example: https://3v4l.org/Xhr68

```
   <?php 
$data = file_get_contents("database.txt"); //read the file
$rows = explode("\n", $data); //create array separate by new line
$rows = array_map("trim", $rows); // for removing any unwanted space
$rowCount = count($rows); // Count your database rows

function CountCol($data){
    $col = explode("|", $data);
    return count($col);

}

 // Creating array from our text database
// in our database first two rows are not needed so I am skipig this 
// by using i = 2
// and $rowCount -1 because of our array start from 0 but count start from 1
// adding $id[$i-2] and like other because of we have started our first loop from 2 and I want to 
// create my new array starting from 0 .

 for ($i=2; $i <$rowCount-1 ; $i++) { 
     for ($j=0; $j < CountCol($rows[$i]) ; $j++) { 
         $column = explode("|", $rows[$i]);

         $id[$i-2]  = $column[0];
         $name_sname[$i-2]  = $column[1];
         $identity[$i-2]  = $column[2]; 
         $address[$i-2]  = $column[3];
         $region[$i-2]  = $column[4];
         $hours[$i-2]  = $column[5];
         $destination[$i-2]  = $column[6];
         $price[$i-2]  = $column[7];
     }


 }

 // let's print our data 
 // I am using 3 here because of we have no need first 2 rows and our array start from 0
 for ($i=0; $i < $rowCount-3  ; $i++) { 

            echo "ID: ".$id[$i] ."<br>";
            echo "name_sname: ".$name_sname[$i]."<br>";
            echo "identity: ".$identity[$i] ."<br>";
            echo "address: ".$address[$i] ."<br>";
            echo "region: ".$region[$i] ."<br>";
            echo "hours: ".$hours[$i] ."<br>";
            echo "destination: ".$destination[$i] ."<br>";
            echo "price: ".$price[$i] ."<br>";

 }

 // 
 // get it like below

echo "printing information using id number <br>";

echo $name_sname[1]; // here 1 is row number or id number
echo $name_sname[2]; 
echo "<br>";


 ?>
```

// but I like to create the database like below. That means no need first two line Columns name and - line

```
1|Ezra Mod1|123456789|husi, stanilesti, vaslui|HUSI - IASI|20:00|HUSI|100;
2|Ezra Mod2|123456789|husi, stanilesti, vaslui|HUSI - IASI|20:00|HUSI|100;
3|Ezra Mod3|123456789|husi, stanilesti, vaslui|HUSI - IASI|20:00|HUSI|100;
4|Ezra Mod4|123456789|husi, stanilesti, vaslui|HUSI - IASI|20:00|HUSI|100;
5|Ezra Mod5|123456789|husi, stanilesti, vaslui|HUSI - IASI|20:00|HUSI|100;
6|Ezra Mod6|123456789|husi, stanilesti, vaslui|HUSI - IASI|20:00|HUSI|100;
```

if you create the database like this below is the solution.

```
<?php 
$data = file_get_contents("database.txt"); //read the file
$rows = explode("\n", $data); //create array separate by new line
$rows = array_map("trim", $rows); // for removing any unwanted space
$rowCount = count($rows); // Count your database rows

function CountCol($data){
    $col = explode("|", $data);
    return count($col);
}

 // Creating our array database

 for ($i=0; $i <$rowCount-1 ; $i++) { 
     for ($j=0; $j < CountCol($rows[$i]) ; $j++) { 
         $column = explode("|", $rows[$i]);

         $id[$i]  = $column[0];
         $name_sname[$i]  = $column[1];
         $identity[$i]  = $column[2]; 
         $address[$i]  = $column[3];
         $region[$i]  = $column[4];
         $hours[$i]  = $column[5];
         $destination[$i]  = $column[6];
         $price[$i]  = $column[7];
     }


 }

 // now we have full control and everything dynamic  let's print
 for ($i=0; $i < $rowCount-1  ; $i++) { 

            echo "ID: ".$id[$i] ."<br>";
            echo "name_sname: ".$name_sname[$i]."<br>";
            echo "identity: ".$identity[$i] ."<br>";
            echo "address: ".$address[$i] ."<br>";
            echo "region: ".$region[$i] ."<br>";
            echo "hours: ".$hours[$i] ."<br>";
            echo "destination: ".$destination[$i] ."<br>";
            echo "price: ".$price[$i] ."<br>";

 }

 // 
 // get it like below

echo "Tow number<br>";

echo $name_sname[1]; // here 1 is row number or id number 
echo $name_sname[2]; 

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is much cleaner...

```
$data = file_get_contents("app/engine/txtdb/tables/sections.txt"); //read the file

$rows = explode("\n", $data); //create array separate by new line
$rows = array_map("trim", $rows); // for removing any unwanted space
$rowCount = count($rows); // Count your database rows

 for ($i=0; $i <$rowCount-1 ; $i++) {
    if($i == 0) { 
         $titles = explode("|", $rows[$i]);
    }
 }
  
  $allcols = array();
  
  for ($i=2; $i <$rowCount-1 ; $i++) { 
         $column = explode("|", $rows[$i]);
         $allcols[$i] = $column;
  }
 
 
  $a = 1;
  foreach($allcols as $colarry) {
     $result[$a] = array_combine($titles, $colarry);
     $a++;
   }
   
      echo '<PRE>';
   var_dump($result);
   echo '</pre>';
```